# Vue js Filters in List Rendering: Best Practices

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm studying VueJs and as programming allows multiple ways to get to the same result (some more or less elegant)...I'm pondering on what is the best way to filter lists.

Here are a few ways i've noticed lists could be filtered:

I will refer to this new Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
     return {
        selected:['diesel','petrol'],


 cars: [
    {
       "color": "blue",
       "type": "diesel",
    },
    {
       "color": "red",
       "type": "petrol",
    },
    {
       "color": "blue",
       "type": "diesel",
    },
    ]
  }
}
```

**Method #1: the "v-show".**
Where any car type pushed into the "selected" array will be rendered.

```
 <div id="app>
     <span v-for="(car, key) in cars"
                    v-show="selected.includes(car.type)"
     >
                {{car.color}} <br>
                {{joke.type}} <br>
     </span>
 </div>
```

**Method #2: Using a computered Property and a filter**

```
 <div id="app>
     <span v-for="(car, key) in filteredCars">
                {{car.color}} <br>
                {{joke.type}} <br>
     </span>
</div>

computed: {

      filteredCars: function(){
             var selected = this.selected

             return this.cars.filter(function(car){

                 if (selected.indexOf(car.type) >= 0) {
                        return joke.type
                 }
             }
      )}
   }
```

Any thoughts and best practices??

Thanks again.

Comment: Typo: Replace joke.type by car.type! ;)

Comment: The best way is go with Computed Proprerties, also this way is mentioned in the Official Docs - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-filterBy-Filter